# What color model does Python's matplotlib colormap use?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, colormap

I need to convert some colors from RGB and for this, I need to know what the color model of matplotlib's colormap is. My best guess would be CIELab but then I'm wondering about the fourth dimension.

```
import matplotlib
import numpy as np

scale = np.random.rand(500)
matplotlib.cm.viridis(scale)

# output
array([[0.175707, 0.6979  , 0.491033, 1.      ],
       [0.127568, 0.566949, 0.550556, 1.      ],
       [0.166383, 0.690856, 0.496502, 1.      ],
       ...,
       [0.169646, 0.456262, 0.55803 , 1.      ],
       [0.139147, 0.533812, 0.555298, 1.      ],
       [0.120565, 0.596422, 0.543611, 1.      ]])
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is RGBA. The fourth number is alpha (the transparency)

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering about the real values between 0 and 1 and I just realized that those are normalized values...